# Adding and/or removing entire drop down select list

Tags: javascript, html

I want when a user clicks a button to be able to add or remove a drop down list for language select and proficiency. What js. code will work for me?

I have tried a couple of different codes from different sources but to no avail!

```js
function addLanguage() {
  var x = document.getElementById("dynamic-select");
  x.labels[x.labels.length] = new Label('-- Choose a Language --', '0', false, false);
}

function removeLanguage() {
  var x = document.getElementById("dynamic-select");
  x.labels[x.labels.length - 1] = null;
}

function removeAllAddedLanguages() {
  var x = document.getElementById("dynamic-select");
  x.labels.length = 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="dynamic-select">
  <label for="dynamicSelect">
   <select data-placeholder="Choose a Language...">
      <option selected disabled value="">-- Choose a language --</option>
   <option value="AF">Afrikanns</option>
   <option value="SQ">Albanian</option>
   <option value="AR">Arabic</option>
   <option value="HY">Armenian</option>
   <option value="EU">Basque</option>
   <option value="BA">Bemba</option>
   <option value="BN">Bengali</option>
  </select>
 <label for="proficiency">Level of proficiency</label>
  <select name="pLevel" id="pLevel">
    <option value="fluent">Fluent</option>
    <option value="fluent">Fluent</option>
    <option value="fluent">Fluent</option>
    <option value="fluent">Novice</option>
    <option value="fluent">No knowledge</option>
  </select>
  </label>
</div>
<button onclick="addLanguage()" id="" class="action_button">Add A Language</button>
<button onclick="removeLanguage()" style="background-color: orange" class="action_button">Remove Last Added</button>
<button onclick="removeAllAddedLanguages()" style="background-color: red" class="action_button">Remove Added Languages</button>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet and fixe the incomplete option

Comment: When you say show and hide, would it be okay to simply hide the entire menu? If so, you could use style.display = "none";

Comment: Are you trying to remove the actual dropdown menu from the screen or are you trying to clear all the items from the dropdown menu and have a blank dropdown menu? Also, if you are trying to clear all the items from the dropdown menu, do you also want the placeholder option cleared or just the real items?

Comment: `x.labels`?????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if you want to do this, but this adds a new selectlist with profession, however I didn't handeld the names of the selectlists, so you may need to add it if you want to post via form.

```js
function addLanguage() {
  var langContainer = document.getElementById('dynamic-select');
  var firstLang = document.getElementsByClassName("lang")[0];
  langContainer.append(firstLang.cloneNode(true));
}
function removeLanguage() {
  var langs = document.getElementsByClassName("lang");
  if (langs.length > 1) { 
    langs[langs.length - 1].remove();
  }
}
function removeAllAddedLanguages() {
  var langContainer = document.getElementById('dynamic-select');
  var firstLang = document.getElementsByClassName("lang")[0];
  langContainer.innerHTML = firstLang.outerHTML;
}
```

```html
<div id="dynamic-select">
  <div class="lang">
    <label for="dynamicSelect">
     <select data-placeholder="Choose a Language...">
        <option selected disabled value="">-- Choose a language --</option>
        <option value="AF">Afrikanns</option>
        <option value="SQ">Albanian</option>
        <option value="AR">Arabic</option>
        <option value="HY">Armenian</option>
        <option value="EU">Basque</option>
        <option value="BA">Bemba</option>
        <option value="BN">Bengali</option>
      </select>
    </label>
    <label for="proficiency">Level of proficiency
    <select name="pLevel" id="pLevel">
      <option value="fluent">Fluent</option>
      <option value="fluent">Fluent</option>
      <option value="fluent">Fluent</option>
      <option value="fluent">Novice</option>
      <option value="fluent">No knowledge</option>
    </select>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
<button onclick="addLanguage()" id="" class="action_button">Add A Language</button>
<button onclick="removeLanguage()" style="background-color: orange" class="action_button">Remove Last Added</button>
<button onclick="removeAllAddedLanguages()" style="background-color: red" class="action_button">Remove Added Languages</button>
```

Comment: @mplungjan I think the same for your answer, because of 'add or remove a drop down list for language select and proficiency' I think he want to add new selects, not options. And he also says for both language and proficiency. I supose, he want to create something like linkedin, facebook and other platforms has when the user can add/select multiple language to his/her profile.

Comment: Hmm, perhaps  So his question says one thing and his code hints at another, Possibly a mix of yours and mine since you cannot add a language

Comment: This answer right here has solved my problem and am all good to go and now on different endeavors! Thank you, @golddragon007, it works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Why `labels` ? If you name the select correctly then this works

I left your inline event listeners but they could be moved to the script too. I change the buttons to type=button and gave the select an ID and used that

Also you had some illegal HTML (unclosed label)

```js
// this code needs to be after the select is defined OR wrapped in an event listener
var x = document.getElementById("dynamicSelect"); 
var len = x.options.length; // default
function addLanguage() {
  var lan = prompt("Language?","");
  if (lan) {
    x.options[x.options.length] = new Option(lan,lan)
    x.selectedIndex=x.options.length-1;
  }  
}

function removeLanguage() {
  if (x.options.length > 0) x.options.length--; // or x.options.length > len
}

function removeAllAddedLanguages() {
  x.options.length = len;
  x.selectedIndex=0;
}
```

```html
<div id="dynamic-select">
  <label for="dynamicSelect">Language spoken</label>
   <select id="dynamicSelect" data-placeholder="Choose a Language...">
      <option selected disabled value="">-- Choose a language --</option>
      <option value="AF">Afrikanns</option>
      <option value="SQ">Albanian</option>
      <option value="AR">Arabic</option>
      <option value="HY">Armenian</option>
      <option value="EU">Basque</option>
      <option value="BA">Bemba</option>
      <option value="BN">Bengali</option>
  </select>
  <label for="proficiency">Level of proficiency</label>
  <select name="pLevel" id="proficiency">
    <option value="fluent">Fluent</option>
    <option value="fluent">Fluent</option>
    <option value="fluent">Fluent</option>
    <option value="fluent">Novice</option>
    <option value="fluent">No knowledge</option>
  </select>
  </label>
</div>
<button type="button" onclick="addLanguage()" id="" class="action_button">Add A Language</button>
<button type="button" onclick="removeLanguage()" style="background-color: orange" class="action_button">Remove Last Added</button>
<button type="button" onclick="removeAllAddedLanguages()" style="background-color: red" class="action_button">Remove Added Languages</button>
```